# Terraform Count for conditional cdn delivery rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I create my cdn endpoints as with the code below. Also I have one variable "environment" which either has the value "dev" or "prod". The delivery rule "DevRedirectToWWW" should only be applied when the variable has the value "dev". Im looking for a kind of if/else statement which allowes me to do that.

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "cdn_endpoint" {
      name                = "${var.environment}-test"
      profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn_profile.name
      location            = azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn_profile.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      origin_host_header  = azurerm_storage_account.frontend_storage.primary_web_host
      is_https_allowed    = true
      origin {
        name      = "${var.environment}-origin"
        host_name = azurerm_storage_account.frontend_storage.primary_web_host
    
      }
      delivery_rule {
        name  = "EnforceHTTPS"
        order = "1"
    
        request_scheme_condition {
          operator     = "Equal"
          match_values = ["HTTP"]
        }
    
        url_redirect_action {
          redirect_type = "Found"
          protocol      = "Https"
        }
    
      }
    
      delivery_rule {
        name  = "redirectToIndex"
        order = "2"
    
        url_file_extension_condition {
          match_values = [
            "0",
          ]
          negate_condition = true
          operator         = "GreaterThan"
          transforms       = []
        }
    
        url_rewrite_action {
          destination             = "/index.html"
          preserve_unmatched_path = false
          source_pattern          = "/"
        }
      }

        delivery_rule {
        name  = "DevRedirectToWWW"
        order = "3"
    
        request_uri_condition {
          operator         = "BeginsWith"
          match_values = [ "https://dev.test.app/" ]
        }
    
        url_redirect_action {
          redirect_type = "Moved"
          protocol = "Https"
          hostname = "www.google.com"
        }
      } 
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn_profile
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a `dynamic` block [1] with `for_each` [2]. The way you would do that would be:

```
dynamic "delivery_rule" {
  for_each = var.environment == "dev" ? [1] : []
  content {
    name  = "DevRedirectToWWW"
    order = "3"
    
    request_uri_condition {
      operator         = "BeginsWith"
      match_values = [ "https://dev.test.app/" ]
    }
    
    url_redirect_action {
      redirect_type = "Moved"
      protocol = "Https"
      hostname = "www.google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each